# Asp.net MVC3 Publish Debug vs. Release mode seems backwards

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build, publish

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and have a MVC3 project, when I do a publish to my local file system, I get a nice really small project package.

So this is what my **Debug Publish** folder looks like

[image: so this is what my debug publish folder looks like]

looks nice and clean to me. However I do notice in the `bin` folder I do see myapp.pdb.

Below is a screen shot of my **Release Publish**, this looks a lot busier to me.

[image: This is my release publish, this looks a lot busier to me.]

to me these two folders look backwards, the debug looks nice and clean, while release looks like what the debug publish should be.

I'm I wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing something wrong (or took the wrong screenshot). The second image shows the file structure of all the files in your project, it's not the publish output.

Comment: agreed publish shouldnt show InventoryLibrary I would have thought as its not required and the code would be in the dll in bin (assuming Inventory library actually contains a component)

Comment: I agree its odd, but that's literally what gives me when I change from debug to release mode and publish to my local harddive.